# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute

Tags: python

I am trying to pass attributes. So I have a class which has 2 attributes say freq, response:
Initially I check no. of arguments given(nargin) if nargin = 1:
I cut the argument into freq and response so as to pass to a function with 2 arguments:

```
def Freq_domain_data_new(*args):          
   S = args[0]          
   obj = FreqDomainData()         
   [nargin, varargin] = foo(args)      
   if nargin == 1:        
      #obj = Freq_domain_data_new(args[0].response, args[0].freq) 
      print(args[0].response, "frequency", args[0].freq)
```

I can see the output as

```
(array([[[ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j]],

       [[ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+1.78200370e-02j,
          2.76164246e-02+3.69176314e-02j, ...,
         -6.19449569e-03+5.94685993e-02j,
         -6.49425365e-03+5.72912490e-02j,
         -6.30085891e-03+5.52413652e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -5.64409958e-03+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+2.92717217e-03j, ...,
         -2.34409953e-04+1.11168204e-01j,
         -2.96739422e-04+1.11054836e-01j,
         -3.20859817e-04+1.10975109e-01j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -3.30150288e-04+1.10923258e-01j,
         -3.46741026e-04+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
         -2.73295572e-04+1.63302152e-02j,
         -3.14846040e-04+1.62408281e-02j,
         -3.24518860e-04+1.61656951e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -3.09627229e-04+1.61104783e-02j,
         -2.80500203e-04+1.60755258e-02j, ...,
          4.46651587e-02+4.55428277e-02j,
          3.55042185e-02+5.20892818e-02j,
          2.46735854e-02+5.61128929e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.26956204e-02+5.74266512e-02j,
          1.47258815e-04+5.59734534e-02j, ...,
          8.24447781e-03-1.11059426e-03j,
          8.71037166e-03+8.26010321e-04j,
          8.75487889e-03+2.73296635e-03j]],

       [[ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          8.36908343e-03+4.51295452e-03j,
          7.56682781e-03+6.07314245e-03j, ...,
          1.01183427e-03-1.47423852e-03j,
          1.37387441e-03-1.13807905e-03j,
          1.67175010e-03-7.40504089e-04j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.88782683e-03-3.01974725e-04j,
          2.00879240e-03+1.53991921e-04j, ...,
          9.21787274e-04+1.11678713e-01j,
          6.13821618e-04+1.11672538e-01j,
          3.21209186e-04+1.11589676e-01j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          7.34031467e-05+1.11458144e-01j,
         -1.12059361e-04+1.11308759e-01j, ...,
          2.19704000e-03+5.18470996e-02j,
          5.25239993e-04+5.10229865e-02j,
         -9.95136992e-04+4.98672311e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -2.27328386e-03+4.84528258e-02j,
         -3.23575567e-03+4.68691200e-02j, ...,
          7.71541300e-04+1.12261234e-01j,
          2.86794931e-04+1.12170169e-01j,
         -1.71608877e-04+1.11965474e-01j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -5.65065234e-04+1.11679634e-01j,
         -8.67122987e-04+1.11350397e-01j, ...,
          1.74310194e-03-7.76130089e-03j,
          3.49617853e-03-6.82626142e-03j,
          5.09010326e-03-5.56856901e-03j]],

       [[ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          6.45197776e-03-4.04128575e-03j,
          7.51641536e-03-2.31147574e-03j, ...,
          5.01873663e-02-1.42387213e-02j,
          5.44862636e-02-1.99470112e-03j,
          5.61427862e-02+1.02832427e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          5.50939360e-02+2.20088482e-02j,
          5.14047455e-02+3.26254085e-02j, ...,
          9.32099581e-04-8.12199847e-03j,
          2.75056685e-03-7.33378635e-03j,
          4.44118399e-03-6.19976017e-03j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          5.92695928e-03-4.76837036e-03j,
          7.13790768e-03-3.10259070e-03j, ...,
          4.09342491e-04+1.59887238e-02j,
          4.77753495e-04+1.61349188e-02j,
          5.02121101e-04+1.62824306e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          4.78498435e-04+1.64143842e-02j,
          4.09443374e-04+1.65162001e-02j, ...,
          2.08096048e-03+1.10791634e-01j,
          2.07696980e-03+1.11282985e-01j,
          1.92309248e-03+1.11708876e-01j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          1.63223032e-03+1.12029008e-01j,
          1.23362037e-03+1.12216569e-01j, ...,
          9.42084800e-03+6.38729058e-02j,
          8.46559123e-03+6.48855335e-02j,
          7.24047232e-03+6.55970583e-02j]],

       [[ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          5.80518610e-03+6.59603907e-02j,
          4.23616465e-03+6.59495142e-02j, ...,
         -1.94784898e-03-4.55469963e-04j,
         -1.88311859e-03-8.42335960e-04j,
         -1.73529279e-03-1.18814856e-03j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -1.51245132e-03-1.48008701e-03j,
         -1.22442576e-03-1.70706382e-03j, ...,
         -7.19711308e-03-6.06231948e-03j,
         -5.99912323e-03-7.19443251e-03j,
         -4.52990960e-03-7.98235958e-03j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -2.85978045e-03-8.39430511e-03j,
         -1.06582113e-03-8.41443101e-03j, ...,
         -2.34361992e-03-5.76961699e-02j,
          1.05610226e-02-5.38494077e-02j,
          2.28875606e-02-4.74130570e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          3.40410110e-02-3.87147475e-02j,
          4.34882259e-02-2.81890444e-02j, ...,
         -5.17261015e-02-4.08138444e-02j,
         -4.37448296e-02-4.92756912e-02j,
         -3.36856051e-02-5.53149787e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -2.20471788e-02-5.86519762e-02j,
         -9.40292415e-03-5.91410743e-02j, ...,
         -8.10480312e-03+1.62808701e-03j,
         -8.63373450e-03-2.96232357e-04j,
         -8.73937886e-03-2.18292093e-03j]],

       [[ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j, ...,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -8.42501600e-03-3.94312414e-03j,
         -7.71410383e-03-5.49716686e-03j, ...,
         -9.60091428e-04+1.50877426e-03j,
         -1.31731727e-03+1.17571237e-03j,
         -1.60392779e-03+7.92888417e-04j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -1.80818690e-03+3.80341417e-04j,
         -1.92333621e-03-4.18821516e-05j, ...,
          3.09671196e-03+4.86273910e-02j,
          5.09211914e-03+4.92400980e-02j,
          6.98676423e-03+5.02204621e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
          8.71031176e-03+5.15298321e-02j,
          1.01980692e-02+5.31202436e-02j, ...,
         -8.56182044e-04+1.10617053e-01j,
         -8.98283441e-04+1.10360102e-01j,
         -8.91155582e-04+1.10074233e-01j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -8.08143975e-04+1.09788987e-01j,
         -6.30922012e-04+1.09541826e-01j, ...,
         -1.48278058e-04+1.60834067e-02j,
         -1.49333723e-04+1.60654969e-02j,
         -1.57614059e-04+1.60297548e-02j],
        [ 0.00000000e+00+0.00000000e+00j,
         -1.62651621e-04+1.59786034e-02j,
         -1.53429403e-04+1.59197798e-02j, ...,
          1.91204240e-04+9.01142745e-03j,
         -1.84876912e-03+8.35345358e-03j,
         -3.78213323e-03+7.28649528e-03j]]]), 'frequency', array([0.00000000e+000, 1.00000000e+007, 2.00000000e+007, ...,
       2.26349788e-315, 2.26349828e-315, 2.26349867e-315]))
```

Now when I run this

```
 def Freq_domain_data_new(*args):          
       S = args[0]          
       obj = FreqDomainData()  #I have a created a class       
       [nargin, varargin] = foo(args)        
       if nargin == 1:        
           obj = Freq_domain_data_new(args[0].response, args[0].freq) 
           print(args[0].response, "frequency", args[0].freq)
```

I get the error stating that:

```
File "C:\Users\nkorgaon\PycharmProjects\HelloWorld\try_nikita.py", line 102, in Freq_domain_data_new
    obj = Freq_domain_data_new(args[0].response, args[0].freq)             
**AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'response'**
```

I am new to python n Stackoverflow :) Would be great if someone could help. Apologies for typos in advance :)

Comment: Apparently, `args[0]` is an NDArray and not what you expected.  You could [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite - working *backwards* from there.  Did you intend to write a recursive function?

Comment: I am not really writing a  recursive function. I am just trying to cut the input into its respective attributes to do some processing on the data. Yes, I realized that the args[0] was an NDarray. So I tried creating 2 independent arrays which would consist response and frequency. Then i tried passing these two as the arguments. In-fact tried converting them to a list but with no success.

Comment: N I have one more question if it had no attribute named **"response"**..shud'nt it be throwing me an when I try printing the attributes?

Comment: `def Freq_domain_data_new(*args): ... obj = Freq_domain_data_new(...` looks recursive to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Yh that's correct! Thanks @wwii for the edit :)

Comment: Please suggest what could be the possible error?

Answer (score 0):

```
 def Freq_domain_data_new(*args):          
       S = args[0]          
       obj = FreqDomainData()  #I have a created a class       
       [nargin, varargin] = foo(args)        
       if nargin == 1:        
           obj = Freq_domain_data_new(args[0].response, args[0].freq) 
           print(args[0].response, "frequency", args[0].freq)
```

Perhaps:
You initially call `Freq_domain_data_new` with arguments whose first item is an object that has `response` and `freq` attributes - its `response` attribute is a Numpy ndarray.  then ...

```
           obj = Freq_domain_data_new(args[0].response, args[0].freq)
```

In the function you make a **recursive**
 call passing an ndarray (`args[0].response`) and something else (`args[0].freq`).

When the *new* function executes that same line, it produces and exception because its `args[0]` is an ndarray.

---

Something like this is happening:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.response = np.arange(5)
        self.freq = np.arange(5,9)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'A instance'    

def foo(*args):
    print(f'args: {args}')
    print('calling foo again')
    obj = foo(args[0].response, args[0].freq)    # <--- recursive call

a = A()
foo(a, 'args[1]')
```

Which results in

```
>>>
args: (A instance, 'args[1]')
calling foo again
args: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4]), array([5, 6, 7, 8]))
calling foo again
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pyProjects33\tmp.py", line 38, in <module>
    foo(a, 'args[1]')
  File "C:\pyProjects33\tmp.py", line 34, in foo
    obj = foo(args[0].response, args[0].freq)
  File "C:\pyProjects33\tmp.py", line 34, in foo
    obj = foo(args[0].response, args[0].freq)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'response'
>>>
```

Comment: That's correct. So I tried manipulating the data. As in stored frequency in another variable and  response in other. Converted it to list and then tried it. But still was not able to do it. What can be done in such a case?

Comment: Sorry @NikitaKorgaonkar - this isn't a discussion forum.  If what I proposed is the problem, you need to refactor and fix it - then come back with new question(s) as needed.  Please remember to use an [mcve] in your questions.